# Cannot log in to smart apps toolkit sample

Tags: cumulocity

I am following the link below to test the smart apps toolkit,
https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/web/smart-toolkit/

I can reach the "5. Create login screen" and see the login page with GRUNT SERVER running in the background. However, I have no luck to login with my account. I got my trial account from telstra-iot.com and my homepage is m2mone.telstra-iot.com.

I change the "demos.cumulocity.com" in hello-core-api/js/app.js to "www.telstra-iot.com" and still no luck.

I put in tenant: m2mone, user name: admin, password: xxxxxx. Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `https://m2mone.telstra-iot.com/` as `baseUrl`:

```
c8yCumulocityProvider.setBaseUrl('https://m2mone.telstra-iot.com/');
```

You can also set tenant there so you don't need to fill tenant in login page:

```
c8yCumulocityProvider.setTenant('m2mone');
```

Now you can leave tenant field empty in login page and if you want, you can remove the tenant field from login page altogether.

Comment: Thanks Mostruash, so do I still put in "m2mone" as tenant in the login page? I was thinking m2mone is the tenant on telstra-iot.com so as www.telstra-iot.com should be the base url.

Comment: Yes you need to put "m2mone" in login page too. See my edit.

Comment: Hi mostruash, I have changed accordingly and still no luck with telstra-iot.com. The login page just blinks after click Sign In button. No difference with setTenant('m2mone') used or not. 
With demos.cumulocity.com as base url, I can login with a cumulocity demo account.

Comment: Let me try it with `testra-io.com` and see what's wrong. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @BillZhou We detected the bug, I'll deploy the fixed version later tonight.

Comment: The new code works with telstra-iot.com now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

By default the grunt server task leads to developer.cumulocity.com which will not work for you because you are on a different installation (telstra-iot).

You can define the host when executing the grunt task

```
grunt server --host=m2mone.telstra-iot.com
```

Comment: That's a different `grunt server`. @Bill is asking about Smart apps toolkit which has a totally different `grunt server` script.